# Get ID of table row in for statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code in my JavaScript:

```
for (var row in $('#alertsbody > tr')) {
    . . . 
}
```

I need to test that the ID of the row matches a value.  However,

```
if (row.attr('id') == myRowId) {
    . . .
}
```

Generates a "TypeError: row.attr is not a function" error.

What's the right way to get the ID of the row?

Comment: HTMLTableRow nodes don't have a .attr method.

Comment: OK.  But what's the right way to get the ID?

Comment: the id is a property, so you can get it directly from row. `row.id`

Comment: `row` is a `string`. What are you ultimately trying to do? I don't know why you'd want to loop a set of rows and test each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery selector returns an array of elements wrapped by a jQuery object.  Using your code, `row` would represent a property of the object, which would work for the numeric properties; but would break for all the other properties (see below for why this is bad).

Again, the following should not be used, but using your code, you would implement the `in` looping construct by caching your selector:

```
var $tr = $('#alertsbody > tr');
for (var row in $tr) {
    // perform any property validation here
    if (isNaN(row))
       continue;                 // try next property

    // id validation
    if ($tr[row].id == myRowId)
       . . . 
}
```

### Warning / Better Alternative

---

This is a bad idea.  This is because you should not loop through the object in this manner, instead you should iterate over the jQuery object using `.each()`.

```
$tr.each(function(){
   if(this.id == myRowId)
      ...
})
```

### Alternative

---

Some alternatives are to skip the loop entirely and select the rows by `id` eg(`$('#myRowId')` or `$('tr#myRowId')`*though, tr is not necessary as there should only be one id per HTML page*) and perform some action.  Or, if you already have some looping construct in place or need an alternative checking mechanism, you can use the `.is()` function:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('myRowId');
var $jqElement = $('#myRowId');

$tr.each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if( $this.is('#myRowId') )
      ...
   if( $this.is( domElement ) )
      ...
   if( $this.is( $jqElement ) )
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll use the `.each()` function.  I do need to iterate over the rows.  I'm actually trying to skip the iteration for the row whose ID I know, not process that one in particular.  I can't escape the test or the loop.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: check out [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/): `$('#alertsbody > tr').not(document.getElementById(myRowId)).each(function(){ /* All rows except the one you know */ });`

Comment: @TonyVitabile or use a better selector `$('#alertsbody > tr[id!="myRowId"]')`

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a `for..in` loop to iterate over the elements of a jQuery collection. `for..in` iterates over all properties of an object, and a jQuery collection has a hell of a lot of properties, only some of which are actual elements of the collection. Use jQuery's provided `.each()` function -> http://api.jquery.com/each/

A sidenote, the variable `row` in `for(row in something)` will contain property names, not the values of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

As you're writing it, you could use the `each` function to iterate, and then JQuery wrap each element before checking the id:

```
$("#alertsbody > tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    if ($(tr).attr('id') == myRowId) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

However, given what you're trying to do, wouldn't it make more sense to just get the element with the specific id?

```
$(myRowId)
```

The only time you'd need to iterate multiple elements would be to select by a non-unique attribute such as `class`, and even then you could incorporate that into the JQuery selector:

```
$("#alertsbody > tr."+myRowClass)
```